# Using derivatives to prove an inequality and, as an application, computing a limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, analysis, derivatives

Show that for every $x \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$

$$x-\frac{x^{2}}{2} < \log (x+1) < x,$$

and as an application, compute the limit

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(1+\frac{k}{n^{2}}\right).$$

My attempt:

Consider the map $f:\mathbb{R}_{0}^{+} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = \log (x+1) -x+\frac{x^{2}}{2}$. Then $f$ is differentiable and

$$f'(x) = \frac{1}{1+x} - 1 + x = \frac{x^{2}}{x+1}.$$

Therefore, $f'(x) = 0$ if and only if $x = 0$ and $f'(x) > 0$ for all $x>0$. This means that $f$ attains its absolute minimum at 0 and so we have

$$\log (x+1) -x+\frac{x^{2}}{2} = f(x) > f(0) = 0$$

for every $x>0$, which implies that for all $x>0$

$$x-\frac{x^{2}}{2} < \log (x+1).$$

Similarly, define $g: \mathbb{R}_{0}^{+} \to \mathbb{R}$ by $g(x) = x- \log (x+1)$. Then $g$ is differentiable and

$$g'(x) = \frac{x}{x+1}.$$

Hence, a similar argument shows that $g$ attains its absolute minimum at 0 and, for every $x>0$

$$\log(x+1) < x.$$

This shows that

$$x-\frac{x^{2}}{2} < \log (x+1) < x,\ \ \text{for all}\ x > 0.$$

Now note that, for every $1 \leq k \leq n$, we have

$$\log \left(1+\frac{1}{n^{2}}\right) + \log \left(1+\frac{2}{n^{2}}\right) + \ldots + \log\left(1+\frac{n}{n^{2}}\right)\\ < \frac{1}{n^{2}} + \frac{2}{n^{2}} + \ldots + \frac{n}{n^{2}}\\ = \frac{1+2+\ldots+n}{n^{2}} \\ = \frac{n(n+1)}{2n^{2}} $$,

and

$$\log \left(1+\frac{1}{n^{2}}\right) + \log \left(1+\frac{2}{n^{2}}\right) + \ldots + \log\left(1+\frac{n}{n^{2}}\right)\\ > \frac{1}{n^{2}}-\frac{1}{2n^{4}} + \frac{2}{n^{2}}-\frac{4}{2n^{4}} + \ldots + \frac{n}{n^{2}}-\frac{n^{2}}{2n^{4}}\\ =  \frac{1+\ldots+n}{n^{2}} - \frac{1+4+\ldots+n^{2}}{4n^{4}}\\ = \frac{n(n+1)}{2n^{2}} - \frac{1+4+\ldots+n^{2}}{4n^{4}}.$$

This gives

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n(n+1)}{2n^{2}} - \frac{1+4+\ldots+n^{2}}{4n^{4}} = \frac{1}{2} - 0 = \frac{1}{2},$$
and
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n(n+1)}{2n^{2}} = \frac{1}{2},$$

which, by the squeeze theorem, implies that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \log \left(1+\frac{1}{n^{2}}\right) + \log \left(1+\frac{2}{n^{2}}\right) + \ldots + \log\left(1+\frac{n}{n^{2}}\right) = \frac{1}{2}.$$

But then

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(1+\frac{k}{n^{2}}\right) = e^{\lim_{n\to \infty}\log \left(\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(1+\frac{k}{n^{2}}\right)\right)} = e^{\frac{1}{2}}.$$

I think the first part is correct but I don´t know if I´ve made some mistake with the arithmetic in the second part. Is it correct?

Comment: Looks fine, but you probably should write explicitely that $1^2+2^2+…+n^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6$, so divided by $n^4$ it $\to0$.

Comment: Your work looks correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @Aig's comment.

Moreover, the last line of reasoning ("But then...") seems unclear to me : I would have written :
$$\forall n\geq 1, \log( \prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(1+\frac{k}{n^{2}}\right))= \log \left(1+\frac{1}{n^{2}}\right) + \log \left(1+\frac{2}{n^{2}}\right) + \ldots + \log\left(1+\frac{n}{n^{2}}\right)$$Then $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(1+\frac{k}{n^{2}}\right)=\mathrm e^\frac12$$